# Wrong set output for intervals

Tags: python-3.x

I came across an interview question and decided to try it. 
The problem is as follows: Given a set of closed intervals, find the smallest set of numbers that covers all the intervals. If there are multiple smallest sets, return any of them.

For example, given the intervals [0, 3], [2, 6], [3, 4], [6, 9], one set of numbers that covers all these intervals is {3, 6}.

My code is below:

```
def findIntersection(intervals): 
"""
find the intersection of a list of intersections.
"""

# First interval 
l = intervals[0][0] #lower component
r = intervals[0][1] #higher component

# Check rest of the intervals  
# and find the intersection 
for i in range(1,len(intervals)): 
    interval=[l,r]
    # If no intersection exists 
    if (intersecting(intervals[i],interval)):  
        print() 

    # Else update the intersection 
    else: 
        l = max(l, intervals[i][0])
        r = min(r, intervals[i][1]) 
        interval=[l,r]

return([l, r]) 
def intersecting(x, y):
"""
Return a boolean indicaing if 2 intervals (x,y) are intersecting
"""
return(y[0] > x[1] or x[0] > y[1])

l=[[0, 3], [2, 6], [3, 4], [6, 9]]

print(findIntersection(l) #this does not work
intervals= [ [ 1, 6 ], [ 2, 8 ], [ 3, 10 ], [ 5, 8 ]] 


print(findIntersection(intervals))# this works`
```

For input l: the output is [3,9] which is not the answer. The output with intervals is [5,6] which is expected.

Comment: I think the easiest way to solve this is as follows: sort the numbers describing the intervals, find the unique values in this sorted list, the smallest set of numbers that covers all the intervals is then `[second smallest number, second highest number]`

Answer (score 0):

It's not easier to work with the intersection funtion from the set-tool.

like

```py
s1 = set([1,2,3])
s2 = set([2,3,4,5])
print(s1.intersection(s2))
```

Comment: In the case of the example that would give a non-intersection, which is wrong according to solution. That's what has been confusing me.